# Problems with PAM module with SSH

Tags: sqlite, ssh, pam

I have a Linux box with some python app running on it. 
The requirement is to allow any logged in user on that app (users are stored in an sqlite table) to be able to SSH into the box.

I'm attempting to use the `libpam_sqlite` library [here](https://github.com/Sectoid/libpam-sqlite):

I've made the neccessary changes to `/etc/pam.s/sshd` as well as `/etc/pam_conf` etc.

`/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
auth        required    pam_sqlite.so 
account     required    pam_sqlite.so
password    required    pam_sqlite.so
```

`/etc/pam_sqlite.conf`:

```
database = /etc/sysdb
table = account
user_column = user_name
pwd_column = user_password
expired_column = acc_expired
newtok_column = acc_new_pwreq
```

I inserted a new record in my SQLite table  that contains a user and a password and it failed.

Here is the error at `/var/log/auth/log`:

```
sshd[2496]: Invalid user timmy from 127.0.0.1
sshd[2496]: input_userauth_request: invalid user timmy [preauth]
sshd[2496]: Failed password for invalid user timmy from 127.0.0.1 port 52220 ssh2
sshd[2496]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

It appears as though SSH is first looking to check whether the user exists on Linux Box before doing the auth via the SQLite tablle (Am i right??)

I then created a new Linux user on the box with the same name as that in the SQLite table (but with different passwords) and tried again and found that it worked!

I tried the following with `pam_listfile.so` as well and found that it would only pass if the there is a corresponding user on the system. (Or I'm going wrong somewhere)

Basically, my question is, in order for SSH to work (`ssh some_user@some_addr`), does the user `some_user` HAVE to exist on the system at `some_addr`? Or am I missing something very obvious??
If so, is there any way that I can achieve my requirement (without multiple SSH keys)?

Thanks in advance for all the help!